# suppressing errors when converting strings to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, error-handling, uniqueidentifier

I have a stored procedure that receives a list of unique identifiers via XML. It is possible that one or more of the strings will not be a valid uniqueidentifier. SQLServer throws an exception upon this conversion and the entire procedure aborts.

Is it possible to suppress these errors and continue? If all but one of the ids is valid I want all of the data for the valid ids, not an error message saying that one id failed to parse.

The relevant select:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Daily dd           
    INNER JOIN dbo.Member m ON m.MemberId = dd.MemberID
    INNER JOIN OPENXML(@hdoc, 'list_of_guids/id/text()', 1) with (guid uniqueidentifier '.') x
            ON x.guid = m.MemberGuid
```

Sample XML, note that the last entry is invalid:

```
<list_of_guids>
<guid>7B8CFAED-8C59-431D-9447-2A45BD4612E5</guid>
<guid>537F4129-0732-4D29-B3B8-4B9127F8522F</guid>
<guid>9965395A-676F-48F2-91CC-F46527D134C</guid>
</list_of_guids>
```

One possibility would be to convert the uniqueidentifiers to a varchar rather than the other way around, but this would cause a performance impact as the uniqueidentifier is an index on the member table.

Comment: Sadly there is no ISUNIQUEIDENTIFIER() complement to ISNUMERIC() and ISDATE(). In SQL Server 2012 you could wrap the last table struct in a subquery and use TRY_CONVERT(). Have you played with any of the newer XML methods? I was surprised OPENXML still works, to be honest. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the open xml isn't going to change the performance regardless of the data type that's found inside. Have you considered doing something like this (largely pseudo):

```
SELECT * FROM OPENXML ... INTO #tmp; -- using VARCHAR type, not GUID

DELETE #tmp WHERE col NOT LIKE '[0-9A-F]...' -- delete those not matching pattern
  OR col IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE #tmp ALTER COLUMN col UNIQUEIDENTIFER;
-- create index here too maybe

SELECT FROM #tmp JOIN other tables;
```

As I suggested this is easier in SQL Server 2012. And I don't think writing those rows to a #temp table is going to change the overall performance that much, if the big help is the index on the GUID column.

Comment: Thanks, this approach does work. The pattern matching in 2008 appears to be woefully lacking though.